# call rest api service from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest

I am trying to understand restful services.i can create a class and define a function into this but when i call it through jquery it return null and when i call directly by typing url in address bar it return a json response

this is the code

```
class Api extends REST 
{
        public function processApi()
        {
            $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("api/","",$_REQUEST['request'])));

            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
            {   
                 $this->$func();  
            }
            else
            {            
                 $this->response('',404);               // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
            }
        }

        private function json($data)
        {
            if(is_array($data))
            {
                return json_encode($data);
            }
        }

        public function demo()
        {
            $error = array('status' => '200', "msg" => "OK");
           $this->response($this->json($error), 200);
        }

}

$api = new Api;
$api->processApi();
```

i just want to call demo method from jquery.this is what i am trying

```
$.post("db/api/demo",
    function(data,status){
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

i am getting response through jquery when demo method is this

```
public function demo()
{
   $error = array('status' => '200', "msg" => "OK");
   echo json_encode($error);
   //$this->response(json_encode($error), 200);
}
```

Comment: try `$this->response($this->json_encode($error), 200);`

Comment: and debug this, f12 on your browser see which url is being hit, also try the absolute url and then test

Comment: Holybreath this is not working . is this ok that i am creating Api object outside the class and now calling from jquery

Comment: will you please tell why this line is not working `$this->response(json_encode($error), 200);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send datatype to server.

Try this code:

```
$.post( "db/api/demo")
      .done(function( data ) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            alert('Data: ' + element.data + ' Status: ' + element.status);   
        });
      }, "json");
```

Comment: will you please tell me how can i call the same method using jQuery `$.ajax` method